# Issue with downloading numpy, aitextgen and other modules

Tags: python, module, pip

When downloading numpy I encountered a failure at the end,

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'c:\\python310\\Scripts\\f2py.exe' -> 'c:\\python310\\Scripts\\f2py.exe.deleteme'
```

and while installing aitextgen i received this error:
ERROR: Cannot install aitextgen==0.3.0, aitextgen==0.4.0, aitextgen==0.4.1, aitextgen==0.5.0, aitextgen==0.5.1 and aitextgen==0.5.2 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.`

The conflict is caused by:

```
aitextgen 0.5.2 depends on torch>=1.6.0
aitextgen 0.5.1 depends on torch>=1.6.0
aitextgen 0.5.0 depends on torch>=1.6.0
aitextgen 0.4.1 depends on torch>=1.6.0
aitextgen 0.3.0 depends on torch>=1.6.0
```

No idea what's causing this. I've reinstalled Python using chocolatey. Is it an issue involving an installation path? Any help is greatly appreciated.I installed these using the `pip3 install [module] method.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I judge your path to python correctly:

> `c:\\python310\\`

Then you have python 3.10 installed. This is at this point only a beta version, not even officially released.

> `aitextgen 0.5.2 depends on torch>=1.6.0`

The issue here is that `torch` only has whl files available on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/torch/#files) and only up to python 3.9. You will face this problem often, as it will take some time, probably after the release scheduled in october to have official support for many python modules.

You options:

1. Install an earlier version of python - this is probably your best option. You probably don't depend on any specific python 3.10 features
2. Download and compile `torch` from source - this will be both tricky, esspecially on windows and is also not guaranteed to work. There is at this point no official support for python 3.10 from torch. You will probably also have to solve a similar problem for other modules when sitcking with pyhon 3.10